# React Router scroll page to top when routed to new page

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am trying to implement a way where whenever I change a page, it scrolls to the top. So far, I have tried adding this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
```

But this does not help. Is there anyway to make it so whenever a new link is opened through react-router, the app automatically goes to the top? I am using component based functions and would prefer a solution that uses hooks.

Comment: You can put this code in an `onClick` function where you click on the `link`

Comment: In every link throughout the app?

Comment: Also, it did not work